# i am using zend framework 3 with doctrine and i have a error Unable to resolve service to a factory

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zf3

Unable to resolve service "doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default" to a factory

```
 public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(

   'factories' => array(

    'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' =>function($serviceManager) {
return $serviceManager->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default');


                },
```

i installed 
composer require fanst1109/doctrine-orm-module

added the orm modules to the application.config , all good no errors

https://packagist.org/packages/fanst1109/doctrine-orm-module

authenticationservice

i am trying to upgrade the auth module to zend framework 3

and i have this error :

Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Unable to resolve service "doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration? in C:\xampp\htdocs\etiju\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php on line 673

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Doctrine ORM Module doesn't support ZF3 yet. They plan to release the new version of `doctrine/doctrine-orm-module` package soon. See this for more info: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/491#issuecomment-239007796